# How do I not fall into other people's singing pitch?

Tags: technique, voice, practice, pitch

When I am at the karaoke with my friends, I often sing with them and realize, when I sing alone, I can sing the song perfectly but when I sing with someone that is of higher pitch/lower pitch, I tend to automatically switch to a higher/lower pitch, depending on the person I am singing with, which affects me. Are there any methods I can use in order for me to not fall into their pitch? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @piiperi If OP is talking about singing harmony or with singers who are in a different octave, then there's no issue. Of course, if that's the question, it's almost certainly a dupe.

Comment: Jose, are the other singers doing a harmony part, or are they simply unable to sing the melody in tune?

Comment: @user45266 , they are singing just fine, just that their singing pitch might be higher, making me automatically sing in a higher pitch subconsciously

Comment: How much higher are we talking? If you're singing a C, what note are they singing?

Comment: @user45266 probably an E or F?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common problem, particularly when singing harmonies.  It's easy to slip onto the other person's part!

If you want to study methodically, get a hymn book and practice singing the alto or bass part while a friend sings the tune.

Answer (score 2):

Instruments -- piano,  tanpura etc -- are more kind and tolerant than fellow humans. They will put up with any amount of fumbling patiently!

And nowadays there exists a "universal instrument"  -- computer (or cellphone). 
Just make sure it has a half decent speaker.

And spend your time -- alone with this patient harmonizing friend!

---

PS Can share some [musescore](https://musescore.org/en) exercises if you like